# Memory allocated for pointer to string literals

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, string-literals

Does an array of string literals declared using pointer waste space like an normal array of strings?

```
char* foo[] = { "bar", "foobar"}
```

vs

```
char foo[2][7] = {"foo", "foobar"}
```

AFAIK, the second case "wastes" memory as the first index only needs 4 but 7 is allocated. Is it the same for the first case?

Comment: In the first case, `foo[0]` may equal `foo[1] + 3`, so the first may take only the space of 2 pointers and 7 `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, with an array of pointers, each string is allocated only the number of bytes needed for its actual characters plus the trailing null.

The tradeoff, though, is that the pointers themselves occupy memory; typically 8 bytes on a modern 64-bit computer.

So

```
char* foo[] = { "bar", "foobar"};
```

would normally use `2*8 + (3+1) + (6+1) =`  27  bytes, whereas

```
char foo[2][7] = {"foo", "foobar"};
```

uses 14.

So if you know that all your strings will be very short, or if they are all very close to the same length, a two-dimensional array like the second approach would use less memory.  If they are of varying lengths and some are relatively long, then an array of pointers would use less.

Comment: I was thinking the same too but I did forget about the memory allocated for the pointers. Thanks for the additional information.

Comment: This answer does not address nuances of where these definitions appear and how the compiler treats data values.

Comment: @Fe2O3: Feel free to write one that does.