Initializing an array of char - Is the string used to initialize the array stored separately in memory in addition to where the array is stored
In the book entitled Understanding and Using C Pointers by Richard Reese, on page 110 the author states

"An array of char can be initialized using the initialization operator. In the following example, a header array is initialized to the character contained in a string literal:
char header[] = "Media Player";


At a later point it states:

"...The initialization will copy these characters to the array terminated by the NUL character, as illustrated in Figure 5-2, assuming the declaration is located in the main function.

In Figure 5-2 (Initializing an array of char) on page 111 it shows the header array located on the stack with its memory address but it also shows the string that was used to initialize the array located in the String Literal Pool at a different memory address.
I find this at odds with what I have read in the book by K.N. King C Programming A Modern Approach 2nd Ed. where on on page 281 an array is initialized as follows

char date1[8] = "June 14"; 

Later on page 282 it states:

Although "June 14" appears to be a string literal, it's not. Instead, C views it as an abbreviation for an array initializer.

Based on the latter text, and my limited understanding, I am thinking that the text Understanding and Using C Pointers is incorrect in stating that "Media Player" is a string literal when used to initialize the array -- it doesn't appear to be simply using the term 'string literal' loosely as a synonym for string as the text then goes on to incorrectly(?) show that "Media Player" is located in the String Literal Pool with its own memory address.
Is my understanding correct?

Are you thinking the following is true? char header[] = "Media Player"; char *pHeader = "Media Player";  header == pHeader 

In the case which you have shown I would say this is not true: header[] is an array of type char and if declared in a function would have scope that is limited to a function and stored on the stack per runtime implementation. *pHeader = "Media Player" : I would say that "Media Player" is an array of char which decays to a pointer to its first element. This is what pHeader will hold. Generally  "Media Player" would be stored in read-only memory, perhaps in the String Literal Pool depending on implementation. It would have static scope. This is my understanding but I could be wrong.

(In the first example) is header global scope or function scope?

@CraigEstey: Neither of those applies. C does not have a global scope (it has file scope with external linkage, which is different), and only labels have function scope. Names declared inside a function have block scope.

The author says " ..assuming the declaration is located in the main function. .." so I would say header has scope which would be that of functions on the stack. In Figure 5-2 the author shows header on the Program Stack

@RadStor Perhaps this Q&A might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78248348/17592432

@Fe2O3 Thank you for sharing this! I do not have a high enough reputation to comment directly on that post so I will comment here. At the start of your post you mentioned (6+1) + (6+1) = 12 bytes. Did you mean to say 14 bytes? ... I am unable to fully appreciate the depth of your post due to my brief exposure to assembly though I was able to take away from your post the importance of being able to differentiate between the VM implementation vs actual (as Eric had referred to in their post as the "abstract machine") and not to form an absolute rigid viewpoint ...

@Fe2O3 ... Is it correct then, to view the abstract machine outlined by the standard as a framework where we can understand the maximums or limits of the language. Therefore; we can be assured that our program will never exceed these maximums when actually implemented?

@Fe2O3 ... To gain a deeper understanding after learning the basics of C, do you think a book such as the following would allow one to appreciate the nuances with regards to implementation? : Writing a C Compiler: Build a Real Programming Language from Scratch by Nora Sandler.

@RadStor Re 12 != 14 :: Doh!! // Re Virtual != Abstract :: Sometimes I get my worms mixed-up // Abstract is abstract which I interpret to mean "conceptual". Consult academic literature from those who have a concrete definition of abstract... Deeper understanding comes with experience. Spock could explain why the sky is blue, but he couldn't understand why that fact was important to people. Do or do not; the choice is always yours.

There are two levels on which we can consider what a C program does. The C standard specifies the semantics of a C program using a model of an abstract machine. When a C implementation translates and executes a program, it can implement the program in any way that produces the same observable behavior, which is how the program accesses volatile objects, writes data into files, and interacts with input/output devices. This allows compilers to optimize programs.
In the abstract level, every string literal causes creation of an array containing the characters of the string literal, per C 2018 6.4.5 6:

In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence…

This array that is created and initialized is different from a named array the program might also be initializing. For example, in char header[] = "Media Player";, there is an unnamed array containing the characters of “Media Player” and a null character, and there is the named array header which is initialized by copying the unnamed array into the named array.
In the actual C implementation, compilers will generally optimize array initializations in various ways depending on context:

For an array of static storage duration, such as one defined outside of any function or with static inside a function, the compiler may create space inside the object module that starts with the data in it. That is, the object file contains one or more sections that effectively say “When the program starts up, allocate memory for this section and initialize it with the bytes here in the object module.” As soon as the memory for the array is actually provided to the program by the operating system, it will be initialized with the data. From the program’s point of view, even using a debugger to peek inside, the named array appears instantaneously with the initial data in it; there is no separate array for the string literal.1
For an array of automatic storage duration that cannot be otherwise optimized, the compiler does need to keep the separate array created by the string literal. Then, each time the array is needed (for example, the function it is defined in is called), the compiler copies the data from the string literal array into the memory for the named array (usually space on the hardware stack). With a debugger, we could see the data being copied from the string literal array into the stack space being used for the array.
If the array is short, the compiler might build its initial data into program instructions. Many processor architectures provide for instructions to contain small amounts of “immediate data” that can be used to build small constants and short sequences of bytes.
In circumstances where further optimization is possible, such as, for example, where the compiler can detect the routine is called only once, or the array is defined with const and its address is not passed outside of the routine, the compiler might be able to treat it similarly to a static array.

Footnote
1 We might almost consider this to be identical to the abstract semantics: The object module contains the array created for the string literal, and the array in memory is initialized with it. Thus, there are indeed two arrays, one unnamed array in the object module and a named array in memory. However, in the abstract model, the array created for the string literal is in the memory of the abstract computer. It would, hypothetically, have an address (even though we never access its address). The data in the object module is not in the program’s memory this way, so it is not actually identical to the abstract semantics.

If I am understanding correctly: In the abstract machine, the unnamed array (in this example "Media Player") is created/initialized and is classified as a string literal. The actual implementation of where/how the unnamed array is stored in memory is implementation specific, and some examples of implementations are of the ones you provided. If one wants to determine the specific implementation of where the unnamed array is actually stored, then they would refer to the C compiler documentation for their implementation ?

@RadStor: The compiler documentation generally will not discuss this. And how the compiler handles the data for the string literal is, as this answer notes, dependent on the situation.

For the implementation which uses the method described for automatic storage duration: If you have multiple named arrays all initialized with the same string literal, then it may be that the implementation stores only a single copy in the string literal pool representing the unnamed array? However if you have multiple named arrays (also automatic storage) all initialized using the same character literals then the compiler might not optimize in the same way as in the string literal case?

@RadStor: Given multiple automatic named arrays with the same initial data, I would expect a good compiler with optimization enabled to put at most one copy of that initial data in the object module, whether it was provided with a string literal or a list of character literals.

@RadStor: In any case, optimization is a different subject than the semantics of string literals. The statement by King in C Programming: A Modern Approach is false. A string literal used to initialize an array is a string literal. Technically, a string literal is the source code, the string in quotation marks. So King is wrong just to start with that. Second, semantically, the string literal results in creation of an array in the abstract model. That is true whether it is used to initialize another array or not. So King is also wrong on that…

… It is only when you get to optimization that an extra copy of the data can be removed.


The initialization will copy these characters to the array terminated by the NUL character

That's a little bit misleading because it implies that the array is copied in a way similar to strcpy, actively checking for a nul terminator. (" " means there is an implicit nul terminator at the end.) That's not how initialization works, so the other book is correct as far as saying that string literals are a special case, in this case they are a form of initializer with special rules.
Consider this simple example:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  char str[] = "Hello\0World";
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof str);
  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof str; i++)
  {
    printf("%c", str[i]=='\0' ? '|' : str[i]);
  }
}

This prints size 12 even though we manually inserted a nul terminator in the middle. And when we print the contents of the array, they go beyond that manual terminator. The code replaces nul terminators with the | for clarity.

Since string literals are initializers in this case, they also come with an unhelpful oddball rule left in the language for historical reasons, namely that if we write char str[5] = "Hello"; then there is no room for the nul terminator and C says that doing so is fine. So that code will silently pass compilation, but now we got a character array which is not a C string as expected because it isn't terminated.

As for why string literals are allocated if at all, that's different from case to case and a topic of its own. String literals: Where do they go? In the case of initialization, the compiler has no reason to allocate the string literal in a string pool unless it is reused by the program several times.
Some examples:

In case the string has static storage duration, then on a RAM-based system like a PC, the string literal could simply be downloaded into the array at startup.
In case of a microcontroller embedded systems where str will be in RAM but the string literal will be in ROM, the string literal will have to be stored in a string pool and copied-down in runtime before main() is executed.
And in case I try this on a local array on an x86_64 PC and disassemble with optimizations (gcc -O3), it replaces the whole thing - my array as well as the string literal - with a "magic number" mov DWORD PTR [rsp+10], 1819043144. Neither the array nor the string literal are stored anywhere.

And so on.


I am thinking that the text Understanding and Using C Pointers is incorrect in stating that "Media Player" is a string literal when used to initialize the array

It is more correct than the King book. It is a string literal and it is an initializer all at once. But as just shown above, string literal doesn't imply any particular form of allocation. The term string literal is rather a grammatical item in the C syntax.
If we untangle the formal grammar in the C standard, then the item string-literal is one form of a primary-expression. From there on all other expressions are derived, depending on which operator that is used, for example assignment-expression. And an initializer can come in 3 different forms, C17 6.7.9 the formal grammar for initializers:

initializer:
assignment-expression
{ initializer-list }
{ initializer-list , }

Where as assignment-expression may contain a primary expression which may be a string literal. This is far from the easiest part of the standard to read.
We may also want to read the constraints (core language rules for initialization) below 6.7.9 where were find things such as:

All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be
constant expressions or string literals.

If the initializer is not a string literal, then how is the author making sense of this constraint?

You provided a microcontroller example where you made reference to the string pool. I recall reading that concepts such as the string pool may or may not be implemented depending on the implementation. Is this correct? If one declares char str[5] = "Hello"; in the main function where the target implementation is on an AVR Attiny85, would the compiler documentation indicate what exactly happens to the "Hello" string literal and where it will go and if a string pool exists for the implementation?

@RadStor The strings have to be stored somewhere and on an MCU that usually means either in a dedicated read-only part such as .rodata or together with the code itself, a section usually called .text (ironically). Easiest way to figure it out is by viewing the "map file" from the linker. "String pooling" can however also refer to an optimization technique by the compiler where it only allocates a string once even though that same string is used at multiple places of the program. A "pool" in programming is usually referring to a place where you can draw resources from.
